# How to write a gradle script, where two tasks has the same dependencies but different configurations

Tags: gradle

Task B is the base task and uses the configuration defined with extension E.

Task A1 depends on Task B and has some configuration E1.
Task A2 also depends on Task B and has some configuration E2.

```
task B // it's a 3rd party task which uses the properties defined in E

E {
    // some configuration
}

task A1(dependsOn: B) {
    // do stuff
}

task A2(dependsOn: B) {
    // do stuff
}
```

If I define it in this way above, both A1 and A2 use the same configuration. But what I want is that A1 and A2 use different configurations defined by extension E. Any suggestions?

========== To be more specific ==========

```
Sync taskB = project.tasks.create("B", Sync)
taskB.description = XXX
taskB.group = XXX
task.with pluginExtension.XXX
taskB.doLast {
    // do stuff
}
```

That's what's written in that plugin, though I substitute the names. Task B is created dynamically and uses the properties defined in extension E.

Comment: `dependsOn` configures execution order only, it's not *extension*. Could You provide an example illustrating problem?

Comment: I use [this](https://github.com/sponiro/gradle-hadoop-plugin) plugin, and it needs to specify an extension named `hadoop`, which specifies buildSubDir and mainClassName of my hadoop application. I wrote several hadoop applications in my project, each corresponding to a different `hadoop` extension, so I want to write different tasks to build my different hadoop applications. BTW, Task `B` corresponds to task `hadoopInstall` defined in that plugin. Task `A1` and `A2` corresponds to my own tasks to build different applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether the plugin supports building multiple Hadoop applications in the same project. If the plugin only provides a single extension `E` (rather than, say, an extension container), there is still a good chance that you can declare additional tasks of the same type as `B` and configure them directly instead of via `E`. If `B`'s task type accesses `E` directly   (which it shouldn't) instead of exposing its own configuration properties, you may have to switch to a multi-project build, or resort to some ugly hacks such as conditionally configuring `E` depending on whether `A1` or `A2` is going to be executed.

Comment: You mean I should write `task C1(type: B){//config E}`, `task C2(type: B){//config E}`, and then `task A1(dependsOn: C1){}`, `task A2(dependsOn: C2)`? Yeah, I tried, it prompts me with error `org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync_Decorated cannot be cast to java.lang.Class`. Actually task B is `Sync`; it seems sync tasks cannot be used as `type`.

Comment: Declaring a task of `type: Sync` is possible and normal. (Of course you cannot do `type: someTaskName`.) Such a task wouldn't configure E, though. Perhaps you can make your question more concrete so that it's easier to answer.

Comment: Oh, yeah, if you will. I use [this plugin](https://github.com/sponiro/gradle-hadoop-plugin), and it adds a Sync task named `hadoopInstall` (what I mentioned as B), which uses the properties defined in the extension `hadoop` (what I mentioned as E). I've already asked the author under his issue. I also post the question here because I think my question is a bit general gradle question.

Comment: I feel that I already answered your question. Not sure what I could add. If the plugin adds just one E, you can't have multiple. Not sure what the problem is with configuring your tasks. You'd have to be more specific.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I understand. "declare additional tasks of the same type as B and configure them directly instead of via E". It seems I can only do it in this way if I insist to write A1 and A2. Otherwise I should make them different projects.

Comment: One more question, you mentioned multiple applications support. Can you give some suggestions on how to write a plugin with multi-app support? So in this case, I cannot use the single extension; then how do I pass the properties?

Comment: The plugin could use an object container (see `project.container()`), instead of a single (extension) object.